# Is there a price too high to pay to prevent secularization in COVID times?

Tags: halacha, pikuachnefesh-danger-life, covid19-pandemic

I realize that the closure of Yeshivos has a huge negative impact on Haredi Bachurim, many of my friends complain that since the boys came home, they went "out-of-sync", don't wake up to morning prayer, don't daven in Minyan, stopped their daily Gemmorah portion, etc.

In addition, many of them expose themselves to radio, newspapers, and, unfortunately, to the Internet and movies through their friends or their parents' devices.

I completely understand, that in the eyes of Rabbinic leadership the future of the community is at stake, and some of them (Belz and Vizhnitz, for example) proposed to let everybody get infected but allow the Yeshivos to operate as usual.

I understand that this can be attributed to the Sugya of "[inciter vs murderer](https://www.yeshiva.org.il/wiki/index.php/%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%97%D7%98%D7%99%D7%90_%D7%90%D7%AA_%D7%94%D7%90%D7%93%D7%9D_%D7%99%D7%95%D7%AA%D7%A8_%D7%9E%D7%9F_%D7%94%D7%94%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%92%D7%95)":

> רַבִּי שִׁמְעוֹן אוֹמֵר מִנַּיִן שֶׁהַמַּחְטִיא אֶת הָאָדָם יוֹתֵר מִן הַהוֹרְגוֹ, שֶׁהַהוֹרֵג הוֹרֵג בָּעוֹלָם הַזֶּה, וְיֵשׁ לוֹ חֵלֶק לָעוֹלָם הַבָּא, וְהַמַּחְטִיא הוֹרְגוֹ בָּעוֹלָם הַזֶּה וּבָעוֹלָם הַבָּא. [Bamidbar_Rabbah.21.4](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Bamidbar_Rabbah.21.4?vhe=Midrash_Rabbah_--_TE&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)

> R. Simeon says, “Whoever causes a person to sin is worse than the one who kills him. Because whoever kills [a person] kills him in this world, but he [still] has a share in the world to come. However, the one who causes him to sin kills him in this world and for the world to come.

With this approach, many elders are risking their lives.

Halachicly speaking, is there a price too high? How lethal the virus should be to allow/abandon this policy?

Comment: Baruch Habba @Al

Comment: Not aware of an exception to the principle of pikuach nefesh which says, “We break any law in order to save life except when this would result in yeshiva boys skipping a daf of Gemara and - audible gasp - reading a newspaper.”

Comment: If the boys are so unmotivated that the only thing keeping them learning is that they are in yeshiva then that's a problem anyway.

Comment: @Al Berko - Similar debate/concept seen in gemora Brachos 61b of which is the lesser of the two evils https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%A2%D7%9C_%D7%95%D7%94%D7%93%D7%92%D7%99%D7%9D#%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%9C where the fox tells the fish to join him and live in safety on dry land....